# Unable to start /plutus-apps client application

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, plutus-starter

Error is occurring for MacOS 12.1 Monterey. Please, let me know, if I should include additional details.

I am going through the step noted in this document in order to setup local Plutus app:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/15QR25eWgg587FTPnuf6Si_lpux-uFQsY_2Gj_4vf4lM/edit

Everything is going fine until the 6th step. The following is the error log I am getting:

```
> plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start /Users/rnaydenov/Desktop/Plutus Pioneer/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client
> plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev

[Info] Running: (Nothing,PSGenerator {_outputDir = "generated"})
The following purescript packages are needed by the generated code:

  - plutus-playground-client
  - purescript-argonaut-codecs
  - purescript-either
  - purescript-enums
  - purescript-lists
  - purescript-maybe
  - purescript-newtype
  - purescript-ordered-collections
  - purescript-prelude
  - purescript-profunctor-lenses
  - purescript-tuples
  - web-common

Successfully created your PureScript modules!

Successfully created your servant API purescript functions!
Please make sure you have purescript-servant-support and purescript-bridge-json-helpers installed

plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: InterpreterError (CompilationErrors [CompilationError {filename = "\n/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-95c26a6de2f74eb6/Main.hs", row = 2, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not find module \8216Playground.Contract\8217","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","2 | import Playground.Contract","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-95c26a6de2f74eb6/Main.hs", row = 3, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not find module \8216Plutus.Contract\8217","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","3 | import Plutus.Contract","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-95c26a6de2f74eb6/Main.hs", row = 4, column = 1, text = [" error:","    Could not find module \8216PlutusTx.Prelude\8217","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","4 | import PlutusTx.Prelude","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]}]))
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rnaydenov/.npm/_logs/2022-01-12T22_40_06_274Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, someone in the discord had this exact same problem.  I had suggested running nix-build, but that errored out.  Apparently the solution was to set this first, before running the command:

```
GC_DONT_GC=1
```

Here is the original message from the pioneers-lounge in the discord: https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/862912746847993887/930825351968473118

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm start` seemed to work .. now off to the next error (: 

Also, for anyone trying to get this setup on Mac M1 I highly recommend this guide https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1

Comment: Actually, for anyone that comes across this: if you manage to get the app running but stumble upon a compilation error of the sort 'Ledger not found', try stopping the client and server, exiting the nix-shell and running `nix build -f default.nix plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab.components.library` in `/plutus-apps`.

According to the ReadMe in plutus-apps https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps this builds the Plutus PAB library required for the compilation.

Comment: This worked for me after "ERR check permissions missing write access", on masOS i7 Monterey.  `sudo GC_DONT_GC=1 npm install -g npm` .