# Error starting /plutus-apps client and connecting to localhost macOS

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, macos

Incurred an error starting /plutus-apps client and connecting to localhost: **user error, Interpreter Error, CompilationErrors**

**Short Error**

```
  plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: 
  InterpreterError (CompilationErrors [CompilationError {filename =
```

**Computer:**

- macOS Monterey (v12.1)
- Macbook Pro 2015 Intel Quad Core i7

**Steps:**

- Started `nix-shell` in plutus-playground-server, and successfully ran `plutus-playground-server`
- In new terminal tab, ~/plutus-apps, `nix-shell` successfully ran
- Updated dependancies `sudo GC_DONT_GC=1 npm install -g npm`
- start client `cd plutus-playground-client` and `npm run start` (**Error occurred here**)

**Full Error**:

```
  plutus-playground-server: user error (Error evaluating simulation: 
  InterpreterError (CompilationErrors [CompilationError {filename = 
  "\n/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-16cc79e7d9a477a7/Main.hs", row = 2, column = 
  1, text = [" error:","    Could not find module 
  \8216Playground.Contract\8217","    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a 
  list of the files searched for.","  |","2 | import Playground.Contract","  
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = 
  "/private/tmp/web-ghc-work-16cc79e7d9a477a7/Main.hs", row = 3, column = 1, 
  text = [" error:","    Could not find module \8216Plutus.Contract\8217","    
  Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  
 |","3 | import Plutus.Contract","  | 
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]},CompilationError {filename = "/private/tmp/web- 
 ghc-work-16cc79e7d9a477a7/Main.hs", row = 4, column = 1, text = [" error:","    
 Could not find module \8216PlutusTx.Prelude\8217","    Use -v (or `:set -v` 
 in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.","  |","4 | import 
 PlutusTx.Prelude","  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"]}]))
```

**References**

- [Unable to start /plutus-apps client application](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6320/unable-to-start-plutus-apps-client-application)

Answer (score 1):

When starting the client server on macOS use `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm run start`.

That is, include `GC_DONT_GC=1` in front of the command `npm run start`.

Then, open a browser tab to `http://localhost:8009/` and, using Brave Browser, Advance from warnings. (*Not* http**s**, see note below).

Note: I had to update my `Plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/webpack.config.js` file per [prodineeritecht's](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6329/4012) recommendation to bi-pass the https proxy firewall.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).